# Density Plotting 2D and 3D

Tags: plotting

(*This was already the corrected code answered to me by @TOMI (thanks to you).  I modified some to fit what I want.  But I still have some issues.

1. The theta which ranges from 0 to 2pi, is presented here as arctan y/x, of course, blows up at x=0. (That we can only use x, y and z as coordinates?) How can I resolve this, knowing that if I use the theta as angle, do not have undefined lines. Thanks in advance!
2. Secondly, how can I change the color for the 3D counterpart, say green.*)

   [Lambda] = 543*10^-7;
   f = 50;
   w0 = 6.275*10^-1;
   zr = ([Pi]*w0^2)/[Lambda];
   theta = [Lambda]/(Pi*w0);

   wz[z_] := w0*Sqrt[1 + (z/zr)^2];

   r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];

   ifunc[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{rtemp, result}, rtemp = r[x, y];
   result = Exp[-2*(rtemp/wz[z])^2];
   Return[result];]
   Color[z_] := RGBColor[0, z, 0]
   z = 1
   DensityPlot[
   ifunc[x, y, z]*(Cos[2*ArcTan[y/x]])^2, {x, -0.2, 0.2}, {y, -0.2,
   0.2}, ColorFunction -> Color]
   DensityPlot3D[
   ifunc[x, y, z]*(Cos[2*ArcTan[y/x]])^2, {x, -0.2, 0.2}, {y, -0.2,
   0.2}, {z, -1, 1}]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `ArcTan[x,y]` instead of `ArcTan[y/x]`

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose I need to add more conditions.  I recently found that ArcSin and ArcCos work instead of ArcTan.  But still asking help for item 2.